# Location of confirm.js

Tags: magento2, locations

In Internet Explorer, I am getting this JavaScript error:

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 42
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: http://example.com/pub/static/version1537326701/frontend/joe/magento-luma-child-theme/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm.js

[image]

My question is, http://example.com/pub/static/version1537326701/frontend/joe/magento-luma-child-theme/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm.js is obviously a cached file, so where is the original file located so I can edit it?

Answer (score 0):

As per your path

> frontend/joe/magento-luma-child-theme/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm.js

If you see `joe/magento-luma-child-theme` path.

It(**confirm.js**) should be in

> app/design/frontend/joe/magento-luma-child-theme/Magento_Ui/web/js/modal(OR
>   model)/confirm.js

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in your question!

Every core **js** & **CSS** file location in magento core module `/projectname/vendor/magento/` directory.

So your **confirm.js** file is located in below path.

> /projectname/vendor/magento/Magento_Ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js

I hope it helps!

Comment: @GTS Joe have you checked my answer? you need any more clarification?